# Using in_array for multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Ok, so I have this array :-

```
0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'receiver_telmob' => string '0707105396' (length=10)
      0 => string '0707105396' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'receiver_telmob' => string '0704671668' (length=10)
      0 => string '0704671668' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'receiver_telmob' => string '0707333311' (length=10)
      0 => string '0707333311' (length=10)
```

And I'm trying to search in this array using `in_array`. But, I never get any true value.
Here's what I'm trying to do:-

```
$searchnumber = '0707333311';
if(in_array($searchnumber,$arrayAbove))
{ 
//do something
}
```

But the if always results a false output. I guess that I'm not using the in_array correctly here. What should I correct to make it work?
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `in_array` for multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array(
   "0" => array(
      "receiver_telmob" => "0707105396",
      "0"               => "0707105396"
   ),
   "1" => array(
      "receiver_telmob" => "0704671668",
      "0"               => "0704671668"
   ),
   "2" => array(
      "receiver_telmob" => "0707333311",
      "0"               => "0707333311"
   )
);

$searchnumber = "0707333311";

foreach($array as $v) {
   if ($v['receiver_telmob'] == $searchnumber) {
      $found = true;
   }
}

echo (isset($found) ? 'search success' : 'search failed');
```

Answer (score 0):

`in_array()` doesn't work with multi-dimensional arrays. You need something like this -

```
function in_multi_array($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_multi_array($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Then you could do this -

```
$searchnumber = '0707333311';
if(in_multi_array($searchnumber,$arrayAbove))
{ 
//do something
}
```

Comment: is that in the manual somewhere? someone else posted this exact same function.

Comment: I've been using this for a long time for multidimensional arrays. Heck I don't even remember how I cobbled it together, just copied and pasted from PHP code I have in a project.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `in_array` for multidimensional arrays!

But this function should work for you:

```
<?php
    function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
        foreach ($haystack as $item) {
            if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

?>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
echo in_array_r("0707333311", $arrayAbove) ? 'true(found)' : 'false(not found)';
```

Comment: you could simplify that a bit: `return (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict)));`

Comment: @Adelphia Yes true!, but for me it would be to nested.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `in_array` `for each` sub array.

So if you have a 1 dimensional array like

`[1,4,43,2,5,4]` you could call `in_array` but when you have multidimensional you have to iterate over the top dimension and call `in_array`

```
 for($i = 0;$i < arr.count(); $i++){
    if(in_array($searchnum, $arr[$i]){
     //do something
    }
 }
```

NOTE: the example above only works for 2d arrays just to demonstrate what I was talking about

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function in_array_recursive($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $item) {
        if ($needle = $item || is_array($item) && in_array_recursive($needle, $item)) 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$searchnumber = '0707333311';
if(in_array_recursive($searchnumber,$arrayAbove))
{ 
   //do something
}
```